# Find not working with mongoose 4.6.*

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Using mongoose if I try to find a document stored in the database using db.model()  like mongoose docs suggests, I get no results :(

However, if I use db.collection().find() I get results.

Why is that? and what will be the best approach using the example code below?

In **app.js**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.connect(config.database.url); // database configuration
app.locals.db = mongoose.connection;

app.locals.db.on('error', function(msg){
    console.log("db connection failed", msg);
});

app.locals.db.once('open', function(){
    console.log("db connected successfully");
});
```

**In routes -> person.js**

```
var Person = require('Person');

router.post('/search', function(req, res) {
   var person = new Person(req.app.locals.db);
   person.getPerson(req.body.name, function(found, docs) {
      if (found === false)
         res.render('pageTpl', { results: 'person not found' });
      else
         res.render('pageTpl', { results: docs });
});
```

**In Person.js**

```
// schema here returns new mongoose.Schema({ fields : types })
const personSchema = require('./schemas/personSchema');

function Person(db) {
    this.db = db;
}

Person.prototype.getPerson = function(term, callback) {
   var Person = this.db.model('people', personSchema);
      var q = Person.find({ name: /^term/ }).sort('age').limit(2);

      q.exec(function(err, results) {
         if (err) return callback (false, err);

         // This returns [] results
         console.log(results);
         callback(true, results);
     });
});

module.exports = Person;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more research I figure out why I was not getting results. It all fall into the details. In Person.js I have the following line:

```
 var q = Person.find({ name: /^term/ }).sort('age').limit(2);
```

If you look closely, the problem resides in here /^term/ where term in a variable but does not get translate into its value. Instead I did:

```
var regTerm = new RegExp("^" + term);
```

Now, regTerm can be used as regular expession within find.

Hope this helps someone in the future.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with this line: `var Person = this.db.model('people', personSchema);`

Mongoose automagically converts model to plural so try the following: `var Person = this.db.model('person', personSchema);`

Comment: In the database I have a collection named: people. I'm assuming and guessing that within the this.db.model('people' ...)  people is the name of the collection in the database? if this is correct: I cannot use any name I want?